# Problems with Qt/C++ echo client + python echo server (no data received)

Tags: python, c++, qt, sockets, network-programming

I'm using this simple echo server in python: http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html
It works with the client in python but I can't get it to wotk with my client written in Qt/C++.
They successfully establish connection bu there is no data being sent between them.
I was able to make my client sent data (for some reason it required forcibly flushing socket after every write) but it still doesn't receive any messages from server. No readyRead() is being fired and bytesAvailable is 0.

```
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include "echoclient.h"

EchoClient::EchoClient(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), serverSocket(new QTcpSocket(this)), networkSession(nullptr)
{
    connect(serverSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &printEcho);
    connect(serverSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(serverSocket, &QTcpSocket::connected,
            this, [this](){QTextStream(stdout) << "Connection established" << endl; messageLoop();});
    connect(serverSocket, QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &disconnect);
}

void EchoClient::connectToServer()
{
    serverSocket->connectToHost(serverIP, serverPort);
}

void EchoClient::setIP(const QString &ip)
{
    serverIP = ip;
}

void EchoClient::setPort(quint16 port)
{
    serverPort = port;
}

void EchoClient::sendMessage(const QString &msg)
{
    qDebug() << serverSocket->write(msg.toUtf8());
    qDebug() << serverSocket->isOpen(); // true
    qDebug() << serverSocket->flush(); // true, why do I need it? It should be working without it
    qDebug() << "bytes available: " << serverSocket->bytesAvailable();
}

void EchoClient::disconnect()
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << "Disconnected" << endl;
}

void EchoClient::printEcho() const
{
    QDataStream in(serverSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);
    QString echoMsg;
    in >> echoMsg;
    QTextStream(stdout) << "Echo: " << echoMsg << endl;
}

void EchoClient::displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError) const
{
    qDebug("error occured");
}

void EchoClient::messageLoop()
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << "You can enter messages now" << endl;
    QTextStream conin(stdin);
    while (true) {
        QString msg;
        conin >> msg;
        sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your Python server supports the format used by `QDataStream`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just stream of bytes?
And, like I said, I manged to make server receive messages from client (via flush). And even if for some reason there was something wrong with formats - it'd should've just outputted garbage. But instead, on one end it says that some amount of bytes is sent, but on the other (client) - it is never received. It disappears.
I think the problem might be similar to flush() one, but python doesn't have flush method and with python client it works fine so there is definitely something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with me forgetting how Qt works. Here:

```
connect(serverSocket, &QTcpSocket::connected,
            this, [this](){QTextStream(stdout) << "Connection established" << endl; messageLoop();});
```

I called messageLoop() at the end of the slot. Which loops. Indefinitely.
So the control is never returned to Qt's EventLoop and new signals can't be processed. I might've thought that any new incoming signals would magically interrupt already running program.

Answer (score 0):

Try debug it using `tcpdump -i lo port $serverport` or similar.
What if you remove `flush()` function frome the code, and listen on that port with `nc -l $serverport` (or whatever you use) and try sending some data back to client?

Upd: it's ok if you get

> bytesAvailable is 0

You calling it right after sending a message. You should call it in `void EchoClient::printEcho() const` method.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm on WIndows.
There is no point in calling it in printEcho() because this method is never triggered (it never prints "Echo:"). And bytesavailable is 0 no matter how many messages I send.